# Difference when pass primitive types and Objects to Conntrollers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm post example, because i'm thinking you are easier understand my question.

I have this HTML markup

```
<div ng-app="autoDrops" ng-controller="testController as test">
    <div ng-controller="simpleController as simple">
        <a href="" ng-click="test.addValue(value, test.testValue)">Add</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="test.addValue2(value2, test.testValue2)">Add2</a>
    </div>
    <a href="" ng-click="test.addValue(value, test.testValue)">Add</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="test.addValue2(value2, test.testValue2)">Add2</a>
    <p>
        {{test.testValue}}
    </p>  
    <p>
        {{test.testValue2}}
    </p> 
<div>
```

and my AngularJs controllers defined like this

```
var autoDrops = angular.module('autoDrops', []);
autoDrops.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    this.testValue = 0;
    $scope.value = 1;
    this.addValue = function(value, testValue){
        //why function not work, if i remove this?
        testValue = testValue + value;
    }
    $scope.value2 = {value:"1"};
    this.testValue2 = [];

    this.addValue2 = function(value, testValue2){
    //this function work with this?
        testValue2.push(value);
    }
});
autoDrops.controller('simpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 1;
    $scope.value2 = {value:"1"};
});
```

Example you can see  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasmin_kurtic/5bL5tfo5/13/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what your problem is. Please explain.

Comment: why my function this.addValue = function(value, testValue){
    //why function not work, if i remove this?
    testValue = testValue + value;
  } not work without "this" 
or why my  function this.addValue2 = function(value, testValue2){
    testValue2.push(value);
  } work without "this"?

Comment: You need to read about the difference in how parameters are passed into functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said @MMHunter this is because in the 1st case you passe a simple value whereas in the secnd case, you pass an array.

Array are passed by reference and value are passed by value.

So if you want to make it works change

1. `this.testValue = 0;` to `this.t = {testValue : 0};`
2. `test.addValue(value, test.testValue)` to `test.addValue(value, test.t)`
3. And...

---

```
this.addValue = function(value, testValue){
  //why function not work, if i remove this?
  testValue = testValue + value;
}
```

To

```
this.addValue = function(value, t){
  //why function not work, if i remove this?
  t.testValue = t.testValue + value;
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

when you are not using `this` ,you are not updating your scope variable, `this.testValue = 0` override it , so `this.testValue` will still print 0

Comment: why this function update scope?
  this.addValue2 = function(value, testValue2){
   testValue2.push(value);
  }

Comment: It's because the data type are not the same your object can be use  by reference but a number cannot.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is that you use object `this` for updating the value.

```
this.testValue = testValue + value;
```

Comment: he knows it, the question is to know why this behavior

Comment: When the controller constructor function is called, this is the controller. When a function defined on a $scope object is called, this is the "scope in effect when the function was called". This may (or may not!) be the $scope that the function is defined on.